# Convergence of a series of not necessarily independent random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

I have been trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $X_1, \ldots $ be a sequence of random variables with $\sum_n \mathbb{E}|X_n| < \infty$. Show that $X:= \sum_n X_n$ exists almost surely and that $E(X) = \sum_n \mathbb{E}X_n$.

I am aware that a powerful tool at one's disposal in such cases is [Kolmogorov's three series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem), whose conditions can be easily checked for this problem, but this does not seem applicable here since independence is missing. If there is a direct argument that can handle this problem, could you please lend me your insights?

Thank you.

Comment: The premise says that $Y := \sum_n \lvert X_n\rvert$ is an integrable function. Therefore the set $\{ \omega : Y(\omega) = +\infty\}$ …

Comment: In general E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y) for any random variables.  Your question doesn,t look right.

Comment: @herbsteinberg In what sense doesn't it look right?

Comment: The number of terms in the sum wasn't specified.   If finite, the answer is trivially obvious.  I have to guess the intention was for an infinite sum, but it should have been stated.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Writing $\sum_n$ for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$, while technically lazy, is quite common and unambiguous... Given that the index is $n$ and there are no other possible upper bound than $\infty$ in the context of the question, that's pretty clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that a random variable is a (measurable) function.

We are given

- a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ (I know, probabilists tend to use $P$ for the probability measure, I use $\mu$.)
- a sequence $(X_n)$ of measurable functions on that probability space (probably real-valued, but it would work the same with complex-valued or $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued functions)
- and $Y := \sum_n \lvert X_n\rvert$ is integrable (that's what $\sum \mathbb{E}\lvert X_n\rvert < +\infty$ says).

Since $Y$ is integrable, the set
$$N := \biggl\{ \omega \in \Omega : \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \lvert X_n(\omega)\rvert = +\infty\biggr\}$$
is a $\mu$-null set.

On $\Omega \setminus N$ the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} X_n(\omega)$ converges absolutely. Defining $X$ arbitrarily on $N$ (assuming $\mu$ is a complete measure) we get another measurable function on $\Omega$, and since $\lvert X(\omega)\rvert \leqslant Y(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$ it follows that $X \in L^1(\mu)$, and
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{\Omega} X(\omega)\,d\mu = \int_{\Omega} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} X_n(\omega)\,d\mu = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \int_{\Omega} X_n(\omega)\,d\mu = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[X_n]$$
follows by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was unsure with what is meant  that the series exists a.s. but from your answer I guess it means a. s. finite?

Comment: It means the series converges almost surely. For series with non-negative (or non-positive) terms, that means "finite", but in general a series can diverge while the partial sums are still bounded. So "a.s. finite" isn't a correct way to put it. But it's common enough to be understood.